# IOS - App freezes in game using Cocos2d

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have just started developing a game, new to Objective-c. Basically at the moment you can move the spaceship around and the spaceship fires continually and there are asteroids coming from the top of screen. But my app freezes after a minute every time why is this?

### CODE

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#pragma mark - HelloWorldLayer

// HelloWorldLayer implementation
@implementation HelloWorldLayer

// Helper class method that creates a Scene with the HelloWorldLayer as the only child.
+(CCScene *) scene
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object.
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object.
    HelloWorldLayer *layer = [HelloWorldLayer node];

    // add layer as a child to scene
    [scene addChild: layer];

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}

// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init]) ) {
        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

        moveLeft = NO;
        moveRight = NO;

        speed = 3;
        fireSpeed = 8;

        fireArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
        CCSprite *bg = [[CCSprite alloc] initWithFile:@"space_bg.jpg"];
        [bg setPosition:ccp(160, 240)];
        CGSize imageSize = bg.contentSize;
        bg.scaleX = winSize.width / imageSize.width;
        bg.scaleY = winSize.height / imageSize.height;
        bg.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
        [self addChild:bg];

        ship = [[CCSprite alloc] initWithFile:@"ship.png"];
        [ship setPosition:ccp(100, 100)];
        [self addChild:ship];

        [self schedule:@selector(fireLoop:)];

        NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                                          target:self
                                                        selector:@selector(fireCreate)
                                                        userInfo:nil
                                                         repeats:YES];
        int t = arc4random() % 5;
        timer3 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:t
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(asteroidTimer)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:YES];
    }
    return self;
}

NSTimer *timer3;
NSTimer *timer2;
NSTimer *tmpTimer;

-(void)asteroidTimer {
    int t = arc4random() % 10;
    timer2 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0
                                              target:self
                                            selector:@selector(asteroidCreate)
                                            userInfo:nil
                                             repeats:YES];
}

-(void)asteroidCreate {

    [timer2 invalidate];
    [tmpTimer invalidate];
    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"asteroids.plist"];
    CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"asteroids.png"];

    NSMutableArray *asteroidAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];

    for(int i=1; i <= 8; i++) {
        [asteroidAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"asteroid%d.png", i]]];
    }

    CCAnimation *moveAsteroidAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:asteroidAnimFrames delay:0.1f];

    CCSprite *asteroid = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"asteroid1.png"];
    int x = arc4random() % 320;
    int y = arc4random() % 480;
    asteroid.position = ccp(x, 480);
    CCAction *asteroidAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:moveAsteroidAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];

    int q = arc4random() % 320;
    int r = arc4random() % 10;
    CCAction *moveAction = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:r position:ccp(q, -50)];

    [asteroid runAction:moveAction];
    [asteroid runAction:asteroidAction];
    [spriteSheet addChild:asteroid];
    [self addChild:spriteSheet];


    int t = arc4random() % 10;
    tmpTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:t
                                                target:self
                                              selector:@selector(asteroidTimer)
                                              userInfo:nil
                                               repeats:YES];
}

-(void)fireLoop:(ccTime)fl {

    if(fireArray.count > 0) {
        for(int i = 0; i < fireArray.count; i++){
            CCSprite *tmpFire = [fireArray objectAtIndex:i];
            if(tmpFire.position.y < 500){
                [tmpFire setPosition:ccp([tmpFire position].x, [tmpFire position].y + fireSpeed)];
            }else{
                [fireArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
            }
        }
    } else
    {

    }
}

-(void)fireCreate {
    int shootPositionX = [ship position].x;
    int shootPositionY = ([ship position].y) + 35;

    CCSprite *fire;
    fire = [[CCSprite alloc] initWithFile:@"fire.png"];
    [fire setPosition:ccp(shootPositionX, shootPositionY)];
    [fireArray addObject:fire];
    [self addChild:fire];
    [fire release];
}

-(void)gameLoop:(ccTime)dt {
    int shipPositionX = 41/2;
    if([ship position].x > shipPositionX){
        [ship setPosition:ccp([ship position].x - speed, [ship position].y)];
    }
}

-(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event  {
    for(UITouch *t in touches){
        CGPoint point = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:t];
        //if(point.x <= 160){
        //    moveRight = NO;
        //    moveLeft = YES;
        //}else{
        //    moveRight =YES;
        //    moveLeft = NO;
        //}

        if(allowedToMove)
            [ship setPosition:ccp(point.x, point.y + 76)];
    }
}

-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    for(UITouch *t in touches){
        CGPoint point = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:t];

        int shipX = [ship position].x;
        int shipY = [ship position].y;

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectMake (shipX - 20.5, shipY - 96, 50, 50), point))
        {
            allowedToMove = true;
        }
    }
}

-(void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    for(UITouch *t in touches){
        CGPoint point = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:t];
        pointXLeft = point.x;
        pointYLeft = point.y;
        allowedToMove = false;
    }
}

// on "dealloc" you need to release all your retained objects
- (void) dealloc
{
    // in case you have something to dealloc, do it in this method
    // in this particular example nothing needs to be released.
    // cocos2d will automatically release all the children (Label)

    // don't forget to call "super dealloc"
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Did you try *breaking* Xcode (press pause button) to see where it's at?

Comment: Press pause in Xcode, see where code execution hangs (call stack). And check that it's really a freeze, not a crash (see Xcode Console for log/error statements).

Comment: You have a repeating timer which creates repeating timers for one thing... your use of `NSTimer` looks nasty and I don't see why you need any of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general track down what seems to be causing it. What does the debugger say? Did you stop the execution or set a breakpoint somewhere that might be problematic? What about exception breakpoints? If those don't work take out your timers and see if you have any change. What about your fire methods?

Also your use of timers look weird and should be the first area you look. Side note, for the asteroids why are you not running the two actions you want to run on the new asteroid using CCSpawn?

In addition are you ever removing projectiles that you shoot from the screen or the asteroids that are no longer needed? If not you should.

But to answer your question the problem looks most likely a timer issue. Your use of timers are wrong. You have timer-3 call asteroid timer, which in turns creates timer-2 that calls asteroid create, which in turns invalidates timer-2 (that had an interval of 0 which makes it look a little unnecessary) and also creates a tmp-timer that calls asteroid create. Timer 3 is left to continuously do what it wants, which is all the steps above, at every x number of seconds. Even though tmp-timer seems to be trying to spawn more asteroid creations and take over the process, instead that looks both incorrect and odd. And you are doing this with a few global timers that can, seemingly have a valid timer but is overridden by a new allocation, just to be invalidated by another method randomly soon after even though what it was trying to invalidate technically was leaked and no longer has a pointer to it, thus invalidating the wrong instance to the wrong timer. Keep in mind your tmp-timer and timer-3 has random intervals. If tmp-timer has an interval of 3 seconds and timer-3 has a 9 second interval at some point something looks like it is bound to go wrong. It is hard to say by glancing at it just how, but it looks inevitable.

Or at least I think that is what is happening. Again the code makes very weird and potentially error prone use of timers.

Also timer-1 is going to keep creating sprites unchecked without those sprites ever going away. Something to think about for sure.

**Edit (Solution):**

If I understand what you are trying to do you want to create timers every variable amount of seconds that, at the end, creates a new asteroid. There are two things that stand out with this. You want something to call the creation of an asteroid, and something else to do the actual create:

```
- (void)countDownToCreateNextAsteroid
{
    int minTime = 1;
    int maxTime = 10;

    int randomTime = (arc4random() % (maxTime - minTime)) + minTime;

    id countdownDelay = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:randomTime];
    id creationMethod = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(createAsteroid)];

    id countdownToCreateSeq = [CCSequence actions:countdownDelay, creationMethod, nil];

    [self stopAllActions];
    [self runAction:countdownToCreateSeq];
}


- (void)createAsteroid
{
    CGPoint someStartPosition = ccp(1024.0f, 512.0f);

    CCSprite* asteroid = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"someImage.png"];
    asteroid.position = someStartPosition;

    // asterdoid dot yada yada = ....

    [self addChild:asteroid];

    float someDuration = 10.0f;
    CGPoint someOffscreenPos = ccp(-1024.0f, 512.0f);

    // Move off screen, then remove yourself...

    id asteroidMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:someDuration
                                          position:someOffscreenPos];

    id asteroidRemove = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^
    {
        [asteroid removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
    }];

    id asteroidSeq = [CCSequence actions:asteroidMove, asteroidRemove, nil];
    [asteroid runAction:asteroidSeq];

    [self countDownToCreateNextAsteroid];
}
```

Therefore in your onEnter you could have something to kick it all off and that's it:

```
- (void)onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];

    // yada yada

    [self countDownToCreateNextAsteroid];
}
```

And the rest would take care of itself. This assumes this quick and simple approach is all you were after. The count down method sets up the count down, calls a method to create an asteroid at the end of that time, then exits. After the asteroid is created a new call to the count down method is invoked, which will setup another asteroid to be created at another random time. This is one quick and simple way to do what it looks you are were actually trying to accomplish with all those timers.